# iOS NSDate from string with time only

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My task is to parse string with time to NSDate. And I do it very well with following code:

```
NSString* timeStr = @"15:00:00"

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate* result = [formatter dateFromString:timeStr];
```

But as a result I get **2000-01-01 15:00:00 CET** and I dont understand why date was set to **2000-01-01**, not **2001-01-01** (which is reference date) or **1970-01-01**. And 2000-01-01 seems to be not random value... :)

Comment: How do you print the `NSDate` object?

Comment: the date is undefined when you have not set it explicitly, on certain cases (=architectures) it is `2000-01-01`, some other cases that is `0012-01-01`, etc... you cannot rely on a specific value if you left it undefined.

Comment: How do I print? Using NSLog? Or even I dont need to print my NSDate object - I just watch it in XCode

@holex How can I set default year for my architecture?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it's just a string with the date part, simply use a dateFormatter, similar what you've done before.

```
NSString* timeStr = @"15:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate* result = [formatter dateFromString:timeStr];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];
timeStr = [formatter stringFromDate:result];
```

Or you need to set date string in date formatter directly, this is because if you specify time string in date formatter you will get combination of date with time string

```
 NSString* dateStr = @"2001-01-01";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];

NSDate* result = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to add date part to my NSDate object, but it is not my question. I dont understand why there is 2000 year, not 0001 nor 1970 nor 2001

Comment: Hope this is the default date we are getting in iOS, when date is not set. Please check the link. Sometimes this link will provide the required answer. http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html

Answer (score -2):

You didn't pass any information beside the time. Any other values in your NSDate are therefore undefined.

Comment: Maybe `NSDateFormatter` or `NSDate` simply initializes the year value with 2000. I don't really see the point of your question. If you want your date-object to have a specific year value you have to set it.

Comment: If you dont see the point of my question why do you try to answer? The question is very simple. What is the meaning of 2000-01-01 date in IOS and why in my case NSDate object is initialized with 2000-01-01 not 2001-01-01. I have had an issue in my application with comparing two NSDate-s that store time only and because of "different date" my comparison hasn't worked. I've resolve my issue by setting date to 2000-01-01 but this value is hard-coded. I think that it will be much better if I get 2000-01-01 date from somewhere.